# A2DP support on Qt for Android?

Tags: qt, bluetooth, a2dp

I was trying to develop an QT Application that streams audio over bluetooth.

So I wanted to know if QT Supports the A2DP Profile and if there is any example code for me to start with. Is there any documentation where I can find out if support is there on not and if I can expect the support in any future release ?

Also, if A2DP is not supported, is there any other profile that I can use ?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: None yet. I am now using native code (atleast in Android) for this purpose.

Comment: Yes the problem is qt's bluetooth does't have sco connection